# R - quantstrat entery & exit on same day using daily data

Tags: r, algorithmic-trading, quantstrat

I am working on a strategy with a daily data. Each round trade happens in one trading day. The entry is at open price and exit is at close price of the same day. Can this be setup in quantstrat? For example if open and close prices for FB on 2021-02-26 are $10.5 and $11.0, then I would like to see the following transactions:

```
> [1] "2021-02-26 FB -10 @ 10.5"
> [1] "2021-02-26 FB 10 @ 11.0"
```

I tried to use allowMagicalThinking argument ... but this does not seem to be working.